# How to convert SpatRaster OSGB36 BNG from degrees to metres in R Terra for United Kingdom / England shape

Tags: terra

I am using the WorldClim data, for example BIO6. I want to clip this to an England shape file and have the ensuing raster expressed in BNG metres. I am unsure of the procedures which involve a few steps and might not be in the right sequence. When I get to resampling or reprojecting I get NaN values.

THIS IS THE WORLDCLIM DATA FILE WHICH WAS REPROJECTED IN ARCGIS TO BNG

```
BIO6.WORLD 
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : OSGB36 / British National Grid (EPSG:27700) 
#source      : wc2.0_bio_30s_06.tif 
#name        : wc2.0_bio_30s_06 
#min value   :            -71.9 
#max value   :             26.5
```

THIS IS THE FIRST SMALLER EXTENT SHAPE I FIRST CROP TO

```
UK.CROP.EXTENT <- rast(xmin=-9, xmax=3, ymin=48, ymax=60, res=1, crs="EPSG:27700") 

#  I CROP TO THIS EXTENT 

BIO6.UK <- crop(BIO6.WORLD, UK.CROP.EXTENT) 

# IT IS NOW SHOWING THE UK EXTENT BUT STILL EXPRESSED IN LAT AND LONG UNITS

BIO6.UK 
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1440, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -9, 3, 48, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : OSGB36 / British National Grid (EPSG:27700) 
#source(s)   : memory
#varname     : wc2.0_bio_30s_06 
#name        : wc2.0_bio_30s_06 
#min value   :             -4.8 
#max value   :              7.4 

# IT LOOKS OK BUT I WANT SMALLER I WANT TO GET TO JUST ENGLAND
plot(BIO6.UK)
```

[image]

THIS IS THE ENGLAND SHAPE i WANT TO RESAMPLE OR REPROJECT TO AND IT IS EXPRESSED IN METRES

```
ENGLAND.SPATRASTER

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 6506, 5698, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 85720, 655520, 7020, 657620  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : OSGB36 / British National Grid (EPSG:27700) 
#source      : ENGLAND.tif 
#name        : ENGLAND 
#min value   :       0 
#max value   :      49
```

IT LOOKS LIKE THIS

[Plot of ENGLAND.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yy8Q.jpg)

```
BIO6.RESAMPLE<-terra::resample(BIO6.ENGLAND, ENGLAND.SPATRASTER, method = "near") 

BIO6.RESAMPLE

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 6506, 5698, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 85720, 655520, 7020, 657620  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : OSGB36 / British National Grid (EPSG:27700) 
#source(s)   : memory
#varname     : ENGLAND 
#name        : wc2.0_bio_30s_06 
#min value   :              NaN 
#max value   :              NaN 

BIO6.REPROJECT <- terra::project(BIO6.ENGLAND, (ENGLAND.SPATRASTER)) 

BIO6.REPROJECT
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 6506, 5698, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 85720, 655520, 7020, 657620  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : OSGB36 / British National Grid (EPSG:27700) 
#source(s)   : memory
#varname     : ENGLAND 
#name        : wc2.0_bio_30s_06 
#min value   :              NaN 
#max value   :              NaN
```

Comment: # Thank you.   
#In fact i found I had loaded this up as an original bioclim file but then i tried to assign the CRS to it and then project.     
BIO6.WORLD<-rast( "wc2.0_bio_30s_06.tif ")
set.crs(BIO6.WORLD, "epsg:27700")  # (ok should not do this )
BIO6.REPROJECT<-terra::project(BIO6.WORLD, ENGLAND.SPATRASTER)
# which resulted NaN   
# the Terra Vignette does state care with setting a crs;
# however perhaps we can say even more prescriptively not to try set up a crs at all; and only to project
# Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You say that `BIO6.WORLD` was projected to BNG, but that is not the case. This is easy to see as the extent is still `-180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`. You probably *assigned* the BNG projection to the data, but that is not correct --- you have mislabeled the data.

What you want to do is use the *original* bioclim files (not the one that you have made invalid with ArcGIS) and project that to `england`

```
library(terra)
bio <- rast("wc2.0_bio_30s_06.tif")
england <- rast(nrow=6506, ncol=5698, ext=c(85720, 655520, 7020, 657620), crs= "EPSG:27700")

bio_england <- project(bio, england)
```